# gRPC import already existing data classes C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I try to use my existing data classes with gRPC
For example I have following data class:

```
 public class Data
{
  public int test;
}
```

How do I use it in my proto file?

```
service Test{
    rpc GetTest (Request) returns (Response);
}


message Request{
    int32 id=1;
    Test test = 2 ?
}

message Response{
    int32 id=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  You can only use other proto Messages inside proto Messages.  You will need to redefine your native data classes in protobuf form.

Comment: How would I use interfaces within my data classes then?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C# unfortunately.  But protobuf messages are data types only; methods would not be supported on them.  You'd want native types that wrap the proto types if you need something like that, or a way to convert between your native types and proto types.

Comment: my intention was not to use c# methods. My goal is to use plain legacy c# classes and types to use them for communication

Comment: The protobuf codegen produces native types that you can use in that way, but there's no way to include your legacy types in protobuf messages without redefining them as new protobuf methods, sorry.